# C# Counting number occurences dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, counting

I'm trying to count the occurrences of some given numbers as the picture shows.

[image]

Giving 5 numbers to the program i want it to output

Número - Frequência R - Frequência A
(1 - 2 - 0.4)
(2 - 1 - 0.2)
(3 - 2 - 0.4)

Frequência R is the number of times that the number appears.

My problem is counting the occurrences of the numbers and setting up the cells with the correct value.

Frequência A is the same since I need the amount of times it appears to divide by the total number of rows.

How would I do this?

Comment: How are you populating the grid? DataTable? List<T>? Looping and creating DataRows?

Comment: I am initializing the one on the left, where i input the digits with dataGridView1.Columns.Add("N", "Nome"); and adding the digits through the app itself, when running.

The one on the right is with dataGridView2.Columns.Add("X", "Número");
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Y", "Frequência R");
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add("Z", "Frequência A");
when pressing the "Frequencia" button

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dataGridView1 is bound to a DataTable (`dt` in my example), or can be, you can do some Linq kung fu to project another collection that can be bound to the second grid:

```
var projection = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(n => n.Field<decimal>("Nome"))
    .GroupBy(d => d)
    .Select(d => new { Numero = d.Key, FrequenciaR = d.Count(), FrequenciaA = (decimal)d.Count() / dt.Rows.Count })
    .ToList();
```

This code gets the list of Nomes and groups them by their value. At this point you will have 3 IGroupings. Then `Select` projects the key of the group (the number), the count of how many are in the group and finally the number divided by the number of rows in the table.

`projection` is a list you can bind to the second data grid. You could of course project into a class type you define.

> UPDATE

You can work directly with the gridview rows though it is a bit more awkward. I encourage you to consider reading up on data binding collections, but try this which does the same as my first example, it just does it against the DataGridViewRowCollection instead:

```
var projection2 = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(dgvr => dgvr.Cells[0].Value != null) // don't count blank rows
    .Select(dgvr => (decimal)dgvr.Cells[0].Value )
    .GroupBy(d => d)
    .Select(d => new { Numero = d.Key, FrequenciaR = d.Count(), FrequenciaA = (decimal)d.Count() / (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) }) // count - 1 to exclude last edit row
    .ToList();
```

If you have LINQPad you can [run my example](http://share.linqpad.net/7v6ksn.linq)

Comment: I added the table as DataTable dt = new DataTable();

Now how would i access the things inside projection?

Comment: I'm sorry, i probably didnt express myself well.
I have 2 dataGridViews, the one on the left where i input the values and the one on the right where they will be sent to. To fill them on the right i'm using 
**dataGridView2.Rows.Add(projection, projection, projection);**, inside a foreach which gets each individual row. My problem is getting the values of Numero, FrequenciaR and FrequenciaA.
Also, thank you for all the help.

Comment: I am suggesting instead of that use `dataGridView2.DataSource = projection2;`